# Is there a way to use long or Unicode filepaths with texify?

Tags: xetex, miktex, texworks, texify

I use MiKTeX and it’s TeXworks and there is the command for making XeLaTeX+MakeIndex+BiBTeX at once. This uses texify and when your file is somewhere in the directory tree where there are non-standard (long or non-ASCII) names of directories or of the file in the path, the texify won’t take it.

Don’t you know if there is a way how to make it work without renaming all the directories in the path to only-ASCII names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be MiKTeX's binaries in general, not just `texify`. I can't get it to work with, for example, `ł` in the file name. It would be best to report this as a bug in MiKTeX.